# Why crypto.subtle can't generate an AES-GCM key with deriveKey usage?

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes

The code below will throw error:

**Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.**

```
const a = async () => {
  const key = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
     {
      name: 'AES-GCM',
      length: 256,
     },
     true,
     ['encrypt', 'decrypt', 'deriveKey'],
   );
 };
a();
```

Why does that happen, I do want to generate a key that can be derived later.

I tried to remove the `deriveKey` usage, but later when I derived it, `permission error` throw.

Comment: You should describe more precisely what you mean by *...that can be derived later...*, in particular which derivation you mean (PBKDF2,...). Also post the code that generates the *permission error*. Otherwise this question can only be answered in a general manner.

Answer (score 1):

> "I do want to generate a key that can be derived later. "

That doesn't mean anything. You either create a key now or you derive it later from a "master key". Furthermore, AES GCM cannot be used for key derivation. `"DeriveKey"` is something that the generated key could be used for, not a property of the key itself.

You can see which algorithms you can use to derive from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/deriveKey#supported_algorithms). However, one is for key agreement, one is for passsword based key derivation and only HKDF seems to fit your needs; if you have a symmetric key and you want to derive another key from it then you should use HKDF.

You can use `DeriveKey` using [`HkdfParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HkdfParams) as first parameter and a `"raw"` key as second parameter (etc.). Unfortunately, no official examples exist for HKDF (but my bug report might get accepted for this, so hey, maybe soon).

Topaco has written a nice answer that includes code for HKDF [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67942717/589259); don't forget to vote up.